# List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> MVC/Angular form save issues

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form to enter a list of key value pairs.  When I enter data into the input fields or add a new keyvalue pair everything displays fine on the client side and I can see the Model updating.  The problem comes when I go to save the newly created list.  The list get passed to the angular save function just fine with all the data in place.  The problem occurs between the angular save function and my MVC controller save function.  The right number of key value pairs get sent to the MVC controller functions parameters, but all of the information has now been set to null.

So on the client side my model looks like this.

```
 [{"Key":"this","Value":"has"},{"Key":"data","Value":"in"},{"Key":"it","Value":"see"}]
```

which is what I want, but when it reaches my MVC controller as a parameter it looks like this.

```
 [{"Key":null,"Value":null},{"Key":null,"Value":null},{"Key":null,"Value":null}]
```

Which is not what I want. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.  Thank You.

Here is my MVC controller function.

```
public JsonResult SaveSettings(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> replacementPaths)
    {
        JobSchedulerConfig config;
        config = Biz.GetConfig();

        config.ReplacementPaths = replacementPaths;

        return null;
    }
```

My Angular controller and save logic.

```
$scope.save = function () {            
        SettingsService.saveSetting($scope.settings)
            .success(function (data) {
                //alert(data);                    
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load data: ' + error.message;

            });
    };

SettingsApp.factory('SettingsService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var SettingsService = {};
    SettingsService.getSettings = function () {
        return $http.get('@Url.Action("GetReplacementPaths", "Setting")');
    };
    SettingsService.saveSetting = function (data) {
        //alert(data);
        alert(data.toSource());
        //data = angular.stringify(data);
        return $http.post('@Url.Action("SaveSettings", "Setting")', data );
    };
    return SettingsService;
}]);
```

And my view markup.

```
<div ng-app="SettingsApp">
<div ng-controller="SettingsController">
    <div ng-repeat="kvp in settings">
        <input ng-model="kvp.Key" />
        <input ng-model="kvp.Value" />
        <button ng-click="delete(settings, kvp)">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addSetting()">Add Setting</button>
    <button type="submit" name="config" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Save Config</button>
    {{settings}}
</div>
</div>
```

Again thanks for any help.

Comment: It is normal to have a quote in '@Url.Action("SaveSettings", "Setting"), data );

Comment: Yes, it has a closing quote on mine, it just got deleted in the copy paste to SO.